# Realization of the Fractional Laplacian Operator in $L^2(\Omega)$.

Tags: functional-analysis, fractional-sobolev-spaces

Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$ a bounded and smooth domain. Moreover, consider that $u(x) = 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}^N \backslash \Omega$. It is well known that Laplace's fractional operator is defined by

$$(-\Delta)^s u(x) = c_{n,s}\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0^+}\int_{\mathbb{R}^N \backslash B_\varepsilon (x)} \frac{u(x) - u(y)}{|x - y|^{N + 2s}}dy.$$

I have been searching with great dedication for a domain $X = D((-\Delta)^s) \subset L^2(\Omega)$ such that $(-\Delta)^s : X \subset L^2(\Omega) \to L^2(\Omega)$ is a closed and densely defined linear operator. Due to the singularity in the integral of the definition of $(-\Delta)^s$, I have not been successful.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, there is some subtlety required in defining the fractional Laplacian in this way on bounded domains because of the nonlocality. In particular, I believe that one has to define an extension of $u$ on $\mathbb{R}^N\setminus \Omega$ to get things to work right. This may be involved with what you are looking for. See Section 2.3 of https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.09767